# why can't I put a number in the event name node js?

Tags: node.js, events

```
var fs = require('fs');

var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+ '/readMe.txt','utf8');

var myWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/writeMe.txt');

myReadStream.on('data2',function(chunk){
console.log('data of read stream received');
console.log(chunk);

myWriteStream.write(chunk);
});
```

This program worked until I decided to put a number 2 in my event name - that is data2.

When I put the number 2 it just won't work anymore, it does not give output error, but it just skips my program.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in node [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) - createReadStream have some event that can happen on.

One of them is `data`. But `data2` is not exist so this event never been called - that why your function is never been executed.

Comment: ouhhh, no wonder it skips the program, now I know, thank you very much, I thought the name can just be any random name

Comment: @iqbalkisas If this answer your question please mark it as excepted so other may use it